# Django Haystack simple search engine issue

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am currently trying out Haystack for our django based forum site.  I was trying to use the simple search engine option but i get an error telling me it is not available.  the haystack documentation says it is still an option and I cannot find anything about why it would not be an option anymore.  Anyone have an knowledge on this?  I am running the latest version of Haystack that i downloaded this morning.  Here is the error:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'simple' isn't an available search backend. Available options are: 'dummy', 'solr', 'whoosh'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s because simple backend not available in 1.0 release of haystack. See the docs  [haystack 1.0 docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/1.0/tutorial.html). 
And i guess you are reading dev docs,which corresponds to the development version on haystack. You can get a  dev version from [github](http://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack).